# AngularJs form submission is not working

Tags: angularjs, controller, ngroute

I am applying a tutorial on routing and controllers.
The problem is that there is no errors, but the form is not submitting the variables into the controller!

i tried another ways to submit the form such as button with type of submit but it did not work.

controller.js:

```
    var app = angular.module('mainApp', ['ngRoute']);

    // configure our routes
    app.config(function($routeProvider) {
        $routeProvider

            // route for the home page
            .when('/', {
                templateUrl : 'login.html'  
            })

            .when('/dashboard', {
                templateUrl : 'dashboard.html'  
            }); 
    });

app.controller('loginCtrl',function($scope,$location){
console.log('login controller'); 
    $scope.submit = function(){ 
        var uname = $scope.username;
        var pass = $scope.password;
        console.log($scope.username);

        if($scope.username == 'Admin' && $scope.password == '123456'){
            console.log('==');
            $location.path('/dashboard');
        }
        else{ alert('Wrong stuff')
    console.log('Error');}    
    };    
});
```

And here is the html pages:

index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>

    <title>AJS</title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.14/angular.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.14/angular-route.js"></script>
<script src="controller.js"></script>

</head>
<body ng-app="mainApp">
    <div ng-view></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Here is the login.html:

```
<div ng-controller="loginCtrl" >
    <form id="loginForm" action="/" >
    <table border="0">
        <tr> 
            <td> User Name:</td>
            <td> <input type="text" name="username" id="username"></td>
        </tr>
    <tr> 
        <td>Password:</td>
        <td><input type="password" name="password" id="password"></td>
    </tr>

     <tr> 
        <td></td>
        <td><button type="button" ng-click="submit()" > Login </button></td>    
    </tr>
    </table>
    </form>
</div>
```

Comment: you did not bind your input type to your controller so $scope.username and $scope.password will be undefined. use ng-model="username" attribute in input type

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You missed the `ng-model` directive in your inputs, which binds the input value to a property on the $scope

```
<div ng-controller="loginCtrl" >
    <form id="loginForm" action="/" >
    <table border="0">
        <tr> 
            <td> User Name:</td>
            <td> <input ng-model="username" type="text" name="username" id="username"></td>
        </tr>
    <tr> 
        <td>Password:</td>
        <td><input ng-model="password" type="password" name="password" id="password"></td>
    </tr>

     <tr> 
        <td></td>
        <td><button type="button" ng-click="submit()" > Login </button></td>    
    </tr>
    </table>
    </form>
</div>
```